# Window load hijacking in flashcanvas with AMD backbone and how to enable toDataURL

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, backbone.js, require, amd

So.. I have a fairly complex client side  js web app using AMD enabled backbone with require.js it also uses the jit infovis lib, everything is cool but I would like to enable some sort of fallback / polyfill for old ie (7,8) I have gone down the route of flash fallbacks which I am resigned to, the rest of the functionality works fine in old ie using excanvas it's only the save canvas to image functionality that is hampering me. Flashcanvas has this concept of checking if its loaded using typeof FlasCanvas to endsure it is defined before it is used , great i reckon but i can never get that to be defined. I will post some code if required but was really interested in the types of answeres that may point to a different approach or experience with loading flashcanvas with require.js for ie. Please don't suggest server side solutions , I know that Its possible somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I fixed it , there is a clash between the version of excanvas and flashcanvas that i am using , i an delegating to flashcanvas alone now and have taken excanvas out of the mix. nothing to see here folks move along...